Hollow boolean no matter what solver I use
I can't get difference Boolean to stop being hollow. Intersect boolean is solid but diference bool is hollow on both fast and exact solvers.
Here's the problem:

Here's the geometry:

Here's the bool object:

Project file:


Yep, all normals facing correctly

Do you try the "Hole Tolerant" option ?

It's manifold. I tried selecting all non-manifold but nothing got selected. Tried hitting merge by distance and 0 vertices were affected. The geometry should be manifold

The normals of the "Retopo_LOGO.001" object are flipped:

In Edit Mode, select all faces, then use the menu entry Mesh>Normals>Flip to achieve this:

Resources:

Documentation to check face orientation
Documentation to edit normals

